# How to get to the top of page without scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

This problem has troubled me for a long time: I want the page to reach the top without scrolling.

I tried this, but it didn’t work:

```
window.scrollTo({
  top:0,
  behavior: 'auto'
 });
```

Comment: where does this code reside? are you aware of side effects in react (and in general)? an invocation on the global object is a side effect, and you should [treat it as such](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Yes, I know, I also get to the top through it, but I don’t want it to have scrolling animation.

Comment: got it now. see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69945832/547020) below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your aim is to avoid the actual scrolling (the "animation"), use [`behavior: 'instant'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo#parameters).

```js
const button = document.getElementById('instant-top-button')
button.addEventListener('click', () => window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  behavior: 'instant',
}))
```

```html
<p>scroll down &#11123;</p>
<p>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</p>
<button id="instant-top-button">&#11121; to top, instantly!</button>
```

Comment: Great, it worked, thank you very much

Comment: glad to have helped :)

Comment: Instant is not on the ScrollBehavior type in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

you need both `x-coord` and `y-coord`

Try this

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

please, try a simple solution.
Just replace your code for this here:

```
window.scroll(0, 0);
```

Cheers,
Marcelo

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work TAT,it keep scrolling to top

Comment: Yes, it will scroll direct to the top. It is like jumping to the top.  I do not know if there is another solution. Yes, you can try to refresh the page but it is not ideal.

Comment: `scroll()` is equivalent to `scrollTo()` - [see MDN for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll#notes)